# transaction-id-prefix need to be identical for same application instance in spring kafka 3?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, kafka-transactions-api

I understand in spring kafka 3, I need a unique transaction-id-prefix for applications running with multiple instances. here is my configuration:

```
fun getTxnIdPrefix() {
    return "$hostname-mytransaction-id-prefix-${UUID.randomUUID()}"
}
```

in this case:

```
hostA-mytransaction-id-prefix-abcd123xxx
app crash and restart
hostA-mytransaction-id-prefix-mnbmgjh698
```

does transaction-id-prefix need to be identical for same instance in case application crash/restart?

I saw from confluent blog [transactions-apache-kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) suggests the transaction-id-prefix need to be identical before/after application instance crash/restart, in order to look for any pending transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be different; however, there will be a delay if there was an in-progress transaction when the instance went down. That transaction will have to time out before a consumer will receive later records.

See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_transaction.timeout.ms